# Broswers loading a page that doesn't appear to exist in DocumentRoot

Tags: linux, google-chrome, apache-http-server, php, mysql

This is driving me bonkers. I have Apache running on a Raspberry Pi and I'm working on a website that has a user log in that leads to a page where users can enter data and send it to a MySQL database. I was working on a file that was called userlogin.php, which I've since deleted. However, every time I browse to sitename/userlogin.php, the page still loads. It loads in Chrome, Chrome Icognito, Chrome after a hard refresh, IE, and on my phone over cellular. I've restarted Apache and the Raspbery PI. Using find, there is no userlogin.php file anywhere on the Raspberry Pi.

Any idea what could be going on?

TIA

**Edit-- Solved:** So, it appears that since userlogin.php didn't exist in the document root, it was redirecting me to index.php without saying so in the address bar. So, while displaying userlogin.php in the address bar the page I was seeing was actually index.php. I discovered this after cleaning up the folder, removing old files that have any relevance anymore; then, one more time I went to /userlogin.php and got the error "**Not found** /index.php does not exist". I could have gone to anywhere.php and it would've shown the same thing.

Pretty confusing.

**Edit 1**: Here are the VitualHost settings, in case it matters

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/asc
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/asc common
</VirtualHost>

<Directory /var/www/asc>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Edit 2:** So weird. When I cat a file and name it userlogin.php that simply echoes 'Hi', then try to load that page in the browser, it displays 'Hi'. When I delete the that new userlogin.php and try to load it in the browser, it goes back to displaying the old version of userlogin.php (which doesn't exist in the DocumentRoot)

Comment: What is the info from the apache log files?

Comment: for the latest load request in the asc common log 
`192.168.1.1 - - [09/Aug/2014:16:49:07 +0000] "GET /userlogin.php HTTP/1.1" 200 6 92`

Comment: then the file is there. just telnet and see it. 200 means OK code